# build variable in Linux kernel Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I am currently trying to understand the build process for the Linux kernel. While looking through the Makefiles, I found several rules in the form

```
scripts_basic:
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=scripts/basic
    $(Q)rm -f .tmp_quiet_recordmcount
```

which all recursively call other make processes and also pass the directory to process. Simultaneously, there seems to be a variable, which is passed, indicating what to do with the subdirectory (the `$(build)` part.

Looking at the make process, as far as I can see, this always seems to be `obj`, I cannot find any other value for this variable so far during the make process. Also, I cannot seem to find any place where this variable is set.

So what exactely is this variable for and how is it used (e.g., where is set and processed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The relevant bit is in `scripts/Kbuild.include`, where it says

```
build := -f $(if $(KBUILD_SRC),$(srctree)/)scripts/Makefile.build obj
```

What this means is that if `$(KBUILD_SRC)` is not empty, the path to `scripts/Makefile.build` is given as an absolute path (or at least with a path that can be found from the working directory) by prepending the path to the top of the kernel source tree. As far as I can tell, this is to make the sub-makes all use the same Makefile and avoid having the same make code several dozen times.